# Wordpress: Multiple taxonomies in same url

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking for a way to list items basing in two different taxonomies in wordpress.

Let's say we have the following taxonomies:

- Category  ( restaurants, shops, cinemas )
- City ( cordoba, malaga, sevilla )

So one post could have city = cordoba and category = restaurant.

I'd like to have a section listing all the restaurants in córdoba.

www. site .com / cordoba / restaurants

or

www. site .com / cordoba / shops

Is that possible??

I don't want to use categories and subcategories since I'd need to repeat all the sub categories for each city.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using typed plugin and custom redirection rules in functions.php, I'll post the code later.

Comment: Can you post the code? Would love to see! Having a similar issue. Thanks